# Может ли тестовый сервер разработки Django обрабатывать запросы нескольких пользователей одновременно как Apache

Tags: python, django

Вопрос в заголовке. Пока нет желания ставить апач.

Comment: Быстрее будет запустить и самому убедиться, чем ждать ответа =)

Comment: Запросы нескольких пользователей - может. Несколько запросов одновременно - не может (и не должен)

Comment: И апач ставить не надо вообще никогда, в 2023 году он просто не нужен

Comment: Т.е. веб сервер джанги можно использовать для сайта с онлайном 100+ пользователей в день?

Comment: Веб-сервер джанги использовать нельзя вообще никогда кроме разработки, потому что, как следует из его названия, он предназначен только для разработки, и для работы с суровым внешним миром его никто не затачивал